# If there are many overlapping polygons at the location of GetFeatureInfo, how can I populate a template with information about all of them?

Tags: wms, mapserver, getfeatureinfo

I have a layer with water basins, actually subbasins. Some of these subbasins (polygons) contain smaller subbasins. If I click on a smaller subbasin, a `GetFeatureInfo` request is sent to mapserver, and mapserver returns HTML produced by the following template:

```
!-- MapServer Template -->
<p>[item name="geographicalName"]</p>
```

While this works fine if there's only one feature (polygon) at the location, if there are two overlapping polygons it only shows information about one of them (typically the least useful, the largest one).

1. Is it possible to write a template that displays information about all features at the location? Some kind of loop perhaps?
2. If not, is it possible to tell mapserver which of the feature to show information for? It should be the smallest polygon (subbasin) at the location (because if the user wants information about the larger one, (s)he can click in the larger one but outside the smaller one).

Comment: Do you send GetFeatureInfo with feature count increased from the default that is 1? For example `&feature_count=10`.

Comment: @user30184 Thanks! I added `&feature_count=10` and now the template displays all features (which is more or less what I want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a WMS 1.3.0 GetFeatureInfo request by default you should get one feature per QUERY_LAYERS layer.  To get more results per QUERY_LAYERS layer you need to add a FEATURE_COUNT=n& parameter to the request, where n is a positive integer.

> 7.4.3.6 FEATURE_COUNT
>   The optional FEATURE_COUNT parameter states the maximum number of features per layer for which feature information shall be returned. Its value is a positive integer. The default value is 1 if this parameter is omitted or is
>   other than a positive integer.